# How to make Selection Sets select also hidden bones

Tags: animation, bones, selection-tools

I'm an absolute beginner with blender and I'm trying to evaluate switching from Maya to Blender for work, but there are things that I can't manage to solve.

Let's say that I have a selection set with all the bones I want to key for a character. I key them all, and do my animation. But some bones switch their visibility on and off during the animation. So if I want to do some retiming that involves the whole character, I need to be able to select and adjust the keys for all the bones, not only the ones that are visible at a certain frame.

For now, I haven't been able to find a way to manage this, cause when a bone is hidden it doesn't get selected, even if it is in the selection set. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "some bones switch their visibility on and off during the animation"?

Comment: I mean that some bones could be hidden at frame 1 and they could be visible at frame 133, for example. And some other bones could be visible at the beginning and get hidden during the animation, and then become visible again. What I mean is that the visibility of the bones changes during the animation, and I'd like to still be able to select them with the selection set even if in one particular frame they are hidden.

Comment: How are they invisible? Hidden by what? If you're talking about object hiding the bone you need to enable the In Front option in the Properties editor > Object Data > Viewport Display

Comment: no, sorry, I mean there's a custom attribute that drives the bone's visibility in the viewport or the visibility of the entire bone layer.

Comment: oh ok I see, I've never used keyframes on the bones visibility